# How to dynamically populate checkbox from database

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-blade

I want to populate the `view.blade.php` page with the value given in `add.blade.php`. I am getting my form values using a variable `$form_value` from the database. How can I use this variable to populate the chekbox in view page.

*view.blade.php*

```
<div class = "row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="hoogwerker"><b> Hoogwerker gebruikt</b>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="koerier"><b> Materiaal toegeleverd via koerier</b>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="bijgewerkt"><b> Kraanboek bijgewerkt</b>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

*add.blade.php*

```
<div class = "row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="hoogwerker"> Hoogwerker gebruikt
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="koerier"> Materiaal toegeleverd via koerier
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="bijgewerkt"> Kraanboek bijgewerkt
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Laravel will do it automatically for you if your blade template is done using Form::model():

```
{{ Form::model($model) }}

    {{ Form::checkbox('hoogwerker') }}
    {{ Form::label('hoogwerker', 'Hoogwerker gebruikt') }}

    {{ Form::checkbox('koerier') }}
    {{ Form::label('koerier', 'Materiaal toegeleverd via koerier') }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

And your controller should do something like

```
$model = User::find(1);
return View::make('your-view')->with('model', $model);
```